# How to serialize an option with serde?

Tags: rust, serde

I have created a `serialize_foo` function that can serialize the `Foo` struct.

`struct Foo(i32)` <- The `Foo` struct looks like this.

The `Foo` struct is used in another struct `Bar` that looks like this:

```rs
struct Bar {
  #[serde(serialize_with = "serialize_foo")]
  pub x: Foo,
  #[serde(serialize_with = "serialize_foo")]
  pub y: Option<Foo>
}
```

The `x` field can be serialized with the `serialize_foo` function, but the `y` field can't. It is because it is an `Option`.

How should I serialize an `Option`, should there be a new function `serialize_foo_option`, but what would the function do if the value is `None`.

Comment: Do you control the `Foo` struct? If so, you should make `serialize_foo` be the actual `Serialize` implementation for `Foo`, and then you'll get all of the composed types like `Option<Foo>`, `Vec<Foo>`, etc. for free.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo No, I am not able to make the actual implementation of `Foo`.

Comment: As suggested in [this](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/serde-serialization-with-option-of-external-struct/67746) thread, you could wrap the `Foo` struct in a wrapper type as shown in [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f42e6ff34e6171af99c432dbbd3b8df1) (always from the former thread)

Comment: You could make an alternate function that does return an option, like `try_serialize_foo`. That really just contains a `map` call on the `Option`.

Comment: You can use https://docs.rs/serde_with/2/serde_with/guide/serde_as/index.html to make it work with any nesting like `Vec<Foo>` or `BTreeMap<Foo, i32>`. The link explains how to use the existing `serialize_foo` function for that.

Comment: @tadman I think this is the best solution to this, but thanks to everyone who helped me with this :)

Comment: If you do find a working solution, a self-answer with your results to confirm would help. Hope that works out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve this problem but this one fits me the best.

I created a new function called `serialize_foo_option` that looks like the following:

```rs
pub fn serialize_foo_option<S>(
    maybe_foo: &Option<Foo>,
    serializer: S,
) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
where
    S: Serializer,
{
    let mut map = serializer.serialize_map(some_len)?;
    if let Some(foo) = maybe_foo {
        map.serialize_entry("key", &foo)?;
    }
    map.end()
}
```

This way if `None` is provided nothing is serialized.

Comment: https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/1301 this issue has an alternative solution which works quite well, although it also requires a custom function

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer, Serialize, Serializer};

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Golden {
    #[serde(serialize_with = "from_evil", deserialize_with = "to_evil")]
    one: Option<Evil>,
}

struct Evil {
    two: String,
}

fn from_evil<S: Serializer>(v: &Option<Evil>, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> {
    let v = v.as_ref().and_then(|v| Some(v.two.clone()));
    Option::<String>::serialize(&v, serializer)
}

fn to_evil<'de, D: Deserializer<'de>>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Option<Evil>, D::Error> {
    Option::<String>::deserialize(deserializer)
        .and_then(|str| Ok(str.and_then(|str| Some(Evil { two: str }))))
}
```

Also make sure to include required serde features

```
[dependencies]
serde = {version = "1.0.196", features = ["serde_derive"] }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you control the serializer function, you can avoid having to write an addition function for `Option`. This is especially important if you have many wrappers, e.g. `Vec`, `Option`, etc.. You can do that with [`serde_with`](https://docs.rs/serde_with), which has a more composable system of [de]serialization:

```rust
use serde::{Serialize, Serializer};

struct SerializeFoo;
impl serde_with::SerializeAs<Foo> for SerializeFoo {
    fn serialize_as<S: Serializer>(source: &Foo, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> {
        // Serialize here...
    }
}

#[serde_with::serde_as]
#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Bar {
    #[serde_as(as = "SerializeFoo")]
    pub x: Foo,
    #[serde_as(as = "Option<SerializeFoo>")]
    // This works as normal:
    // #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub y: Option<Foo>,
}
```